# Sudden arrival of acrid smell in one bedroom

Tags: smell

At first, I thought it was coming from the ensuite bathroom but after keeping both doors to the bedroom closed for just a few minutes it was only in the bedroom.

It is a smell that I associate with cat hormones (we have never had them) and stays in the back of my nose for ages after I have experienced it.  My husband (who sleeps in this room) is unconcerned by it and thinks it smells of wood polish.  I could not spend time with this smell because it stays in my head!

It does not seem to be coming from any cupboards or drawers and I experience it as strongest close to the bathroom door, though once through the door and with it closed behind, the bathroom smells sweet.
I'm not sure if acrid is the right description. But it is a very definite smell that I don't associate with drains or with dead rats (which I have experienced).

Any help much appreciated.  What I dread is that it turns up in another room.

Comment: Sudden arrival is usually due to a spill or major weather in the recent(week or two) past.  Mold is also a possibility, usually from a leak, either plumbing or roof/walls.  Will probably need someone to look for it and it might require some of the flooring/trim/wall to be opened up.

Comment: An "acrid" odor could be due to an electrical fault-- loose connection causing arcing leading to ozone generation or overheating wire buring the insulation. A sharp and pungent odor could be rodent urine.

Comment: Could be a dead mouse (or other critter) in the wall or ceiling... ?

Answer (score 1):

Does it smell like ammonia?
Ammonia is found is cat (and all mammal) urine and smells 'pungent'. Compare the smell with smelling salts or some ammonia-based household cleaners. [1] Just be careful to waft and not inhale directly.

If it's ammonia, first consider some health conditions cause sweat to smell like ammonia. [2]

Zeolite is a porous rock that is a great adsorber of ammonia and is available to purchase online. [3]

Good luck.

[1] [https://www.amazon.com/Awesome-Products-Totally-Pure-Ammonia/dp/B008XY2012](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B008XY2012)

[2] https://www.medicalnewstoday.com/articles/sweat-smells-like-ammonia

[3] https://shop.kmizeolite.com/shop/kmi-zeolite-10#attr=1,20

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/167386)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that a Tom may have entered the house before you moved in (or after) and has sprayed somewhere.

It is very very hard to get rid of the chemical (and the smell).  Apart from the smell it is very corrosive to metal.

If you can't find the spot, then try overpowering or neutralizing it. Amazon has many products for different parts of your house.

My experience was when I was moving houses, a neighbor's Tom did the deed on my PC. The chassis kept corroding and the smell did not leave for months.

> The most effective way to neutralize a cat urine smell is with an enzyme cleaner.

From [Removing Foul Smelling Cat Odors From Your Home](https://www.hillspet.com/cat-care/resources/getting-rid-of-cat-odors?lightboxfired=true#).  Not my website, its hillspet.com